# Mysql one to none or many join

Tags: mysql, join, one-to-many, right-to-left

I know that there are a lot of questions close to this one, but non of them solved my problem.

Lets say that i have 2 tabels, TableA and TableB

TableA have: id and name

TableB have: id, TableA_id and date

I want to get TableA LEFT JOIN with the newest record of TableB IF any.

```
SELECT `TableA`.`id` AS `TableA_ID`, `TableB`.`id` AS `TableB_ID` 
FROM `TableA` 
LEFT JOIN TableB` ON `TableA`.`id` = `TableB`.`id`
```

I want the TableA fields even if there is nothing to join from table b.
And if there is something to join from TableB then I want the newest one.

I know that this can be made with a subquery, but I would like to know if there is a way to LEFT JOIN it.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.id,b.id from tableA a left join tableB b on a.id = b.id 
order by b.id desc
```

Comment: This will not solve the issue, as I only want one row for each item in TableA, and group by will not fully solve it ether.

Comment: Use Distinct clause and MAX() clause where date is involved.

Comment: This could be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is the proper syntax in mysql, but in mssql it would look like as follows

```
SELECT `TableA`.`id` AS `TableA_ID`, `new_table_b`.`id` AS `TableB_ID` 
FROM `TableA` 
LEFT JOIN (select id, max(date) from tableB group by id) new_table_b ON `TableA`.`id` = `new_table_b`.`id`
```

Comment: I want to make a full join where I get all the values from TableB at my disposal, if possible.

Comment: In the question you mentioned that you want to fetch all rows from tableA in this case left join will do the job, if you'll use full join then expect to get null rows from tableA since potentially there will be rows in tableb which won't match tableA ids